# What's the difference in both the code snippets? How does it matter to compiler if I am not telling how many bytes needed for array

Tags: c, concatenation, c-strings

The basic program of concatenating two strings. I am not getting the point of how not defining the length of str1 array is leading to core dump.

If I define the length of str1 let's say to str1[100] then the program is working fine.

```
void myStrcat(char *a, char *b)
{
    int m = strlen(a);
    int n = strlen(b);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++){
       a[m+i]  = b[i];
    }

}

int main()
{
    char str1[] = "String1 ";
    char *str2 = "String2";
    myStrcat(str1, str2);
    printf("%s ", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

*** stack smashing detected ***:  terminated
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

char str1[] = "String1 " declares an array with 9 characters (the last character indicate the end of the array = '\0'). So any operation which try to modify the field out off the 9 characters will lead to an undefined behaviour and a dump.

Answer (score 0):

> How does it matter to compiler if I am not telling how many bytes needed for array?

It matters a great deal, because if you're not telling, it means *nobody's* telling, so whatever size the array has, chances are it's not big enough.

One of the things that makes C difficult to learn is that there is not a true "string" type.  Strings don't get handled for you automatically.  It's generally *your* responsibility to explicitly allocate the memory required for any strings you construct.

In the program you posted,
`str1` is just big enough for `"String1 "` (and no bigger), and `str2`
is just big enough  for `"String2"` (and no bigger), and nowhere is
there memory allocated for the concatenated string `"String1 String2"`.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question at the beginning:

> If I define the length of str1 let's say to str1[100] then the program
>   is working fine.

Strings in C are simply arrays of specific length. When you use the shortcut `char str1[] = "String1 "` you are asking the compiler to do the math for you and determine the array size from the string literal you provided. In this case, 9 bytes (8 for the characters you specified - including the space at the end, plus a `0` byte as a string delimiter.

This is identical to `char str1[9] = "String1 "` and therefore, when you try to concatenate `str2` into `str1` you start writing beyond the end of the memory allocated for `str1`. So you can see that you have room when you specify `char str1[100]` or even `str[20]` for that matter.

Note that in C, the variables with scope inside a function, such as your strings are placed on the stack - and therefore, you get the error message about "stack smashing". The nice thing about them being on the stack is that when you return from your function, the memory is automatically available. The bad thing is that on certain (older or embedded) systems it's possible to run out of stack space.